# Formula giving result based on data on two columns

Tags: excel-formula, formula

I have a dataset from which I am trying to extract answers. The data relates to work processed which goes through steps, and log numbers are created for errors later found and attributed to the appropriate step. They can be attributed to multiple steps.

The steps involved are index, process, QC. What I am trying to figure out is whether the work passed through quality control and show the result.

I have managed to create a formula which partially works. However, when the work with matching log numbers has both index and process, or was processed by two people in the step columns, it is giving the incorrect result.

```
=IF(G2="QC","QC",IF(COUNTIF(W:W,W2)=1,"UNCHECKED","CHECKED"))
```

Where column G contains step information and column W the log number.

[example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoacf.png)
The results in red are incorrect.

The logic is as follows:

- where step equals QC, result should equal "QC"

where step is other than QC

- and log number is unique, result should be "unchecked"
- the log number is duplicated with a step other than QC, result should be "unchecked"
- the log number is duplicated with a step including QC, result should
  be "checked"

Comment: Please include a snippet of your data (or a mockup of similar data) and HOW the formula is off.  What were you expecting and what did it show?

Comment: I struggled to post a data example that was well formatted.

Comment: I'll edit my question to give more detail on the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it doesn't matter whether item is unique or not, it's "CHECKED" as long as there is a line with "QC" for this log elsewhere in the table, is that right?

My modification:

```
=IF(G2="QC",
   "QC",
   IF(COUNTIFS(W:W,W2, G:G,"QC")>0, 
     "CHECKED", 
     "UNCHECKED"
     )
   )
```

I am not sure why you have QC and CHECKED for what seems to mean the same thing. If it's the case, then first part of IF would be

```
=IF(G2="QC", "CHECKED"....
```

Comment: Yes, this seems like a logical simplification of mine. Nice work.

Comment: The first part of your answer is exactly what I was looking for. I probably should have mentioned before but the reason why the formula is required is so we can evaluate whether too much of a persons work is passing through unchecked, the volume of work that is being checked but still has errors or if a person is checking work and they are letting too many errors through. Hence the difference between QC and Checked results. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=IF(G2="QC","QC",IF(COUNTIF(W:W,G2)=1,"UNCHECKED",IF(COUNTIFS(G:G,"QC",W:W,W2)>0,"CHECKED","UNCHECKED")))
```

You needed an additional IF() statement at the end to check if the same Log Number occurred with "QC".

Comment: Jacob, I had the same idea but i don't think you need IF(COUNTIF(W:W,G2)=1 part

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I tried this and the QC results were correct but everything else was showing as "Unchecked". I'm not sure if the w:w,g2 part is the cause. However, the first part of Lana's answer has solved the issue. Many thanks